# header not showing in ionic

Tags: html, ionic-framework

ion-view header bar is not displaying in my ionic app. can anyone tell me about the issue? i;ve tried aloot of things to fix it but nothing happens.

**Offer.html**

```
<ion-view style="font-family: 'Lobster', cursive; " view-title="Ad's Cafe">

<ion-nav-bar class="bar-assertive">

<ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>

  <ion-content   class="has-header">
    <ion-list>
       <button style="font-family: 'Cherry Cream Soda', cursive; "class="button button-full button-stable">
            <i class="ion-speakerphone"></i>
                Offer Details
        </button>
     <ion-item ng-repeat="offer in offers ">
        <div class="list card">
        <div class="item item-text-wrap item-divider">
          <u> <h1><i class="ion-android-restaurante"></i>{{offer.Title}}  </h1> </u>
        </div>
         <div class="item item-text-wrap">
               <u><img style=" border: 1px solid black;

                width: 100%;
                height: auto"   class="img-responsive " ng-src="{{offer.link}} "
               >      </u>

        </div>
        <div class="item item-text-wrap">
          <h3> {{offer.Desc}} </h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to close `</ion-nav-bar>`

```
<ion-view style="font-family: 'Lobster', cursive; " view-title="Ad's Cafe">

<ion-nav-bar class="bar-assertive">

<ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>

</ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-content   class="has-header">
    <ion-list>
       <button style="font-family: 'Cherry Cream Soda', cursive; "class="button button-full button-stable">
            <i class="ion-speakerphone"></i>
                Offer Details
        </button>
     <ion-item ng-repeat="offer in offers ">
        <div class="list card">
        <div class="item item-text-wrap item-divider">
          <u> <h1><i class="ion-android-restaurante"></i>{{offer.Title}}  </h1> </u>
        </div>
         <div class="item item-text-wrap">
               <u><img style=" border: 1px solid black;

                width: 100%;
                height: auto"   class="img-responsive " ng-src="{{offer.link}} "
               >      </u>

        </div>
        <div class="item item-text-wrap">
          <h3> {{offer.Desc}} </h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```